# Flask: Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process

Tags: python-3.x, flask

spotifywebapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.13.18.150
    WSGIDaemonProcess spotifywebapp request-timeout=600 threads=5 user=www-data group=www-data
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/spotifywebapp/piapp.wsgi
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    <Directory "/var/www/spotifywebapp">
        WSGIProcessGroup spotifywebapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/spotifywebapp/logs/error.logs
    CustomLog /var/www/spotifywebapp/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

piapp.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/var/www/spotifywebapp/venv/bin/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/spotifywebapp')

from piapp import app as application
```

I have a Flask server site served from Apache + ModWSGI on Ubuntu  there is a certain library called spotipy. When I able to call this library in my code SpotifyOAuth() it hangs and unable to redirect to the next respective webpage. The error which is coming is

Error: Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'spotifywebapp': /var/www/spotifywebapp/piapp.wsgi

Based on other forums I used to give Timeout 6000 and WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in apache.conf file. But it didint solve. Is there any solution to rectify this problem